# Unable to crop the image in PrimeFaces using ImageCropper

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

In my project I have to use Image Cropper to crop an image. I tried the image cropper showcase example but when I click the crop button it throws an error

```
.j_id_8:j_id_b: Conversion error occurred.
```

and it doesn't call crop method. I am struck on the error message and the error isn't cleared. How to fix this problem?

XHTML Page

```
<ui:define name="centerPageContent">
<h:form id="profilePictureForm">
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:imageCropper value="#{profilePicture.croppedImage}" image="#{profilePicture.sampleImage}" initialCoords="225,75,300,125" />
        <p:graphicImage id="localCroppedImage" value="../images/images1.jpg" /> </h:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="Crop" action="#{profilePicture.crop}" update="localCroppedImage" /> </h:form>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: mention `id` attribute to primefaces components.

Comment: Do you can write your **xhtml**?

Comment: XHTML Page<ui:define name="centerPageContent">
  <h:form id="profilePictureForm">
   <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"
    closable="true" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:imageCropper value="#{profilePicture.croppedImage}"
     image="#{profilePicture.sampleImage}" initialCoords="225,75,300,125" />
    <p:graphicImage id="localCroppedImage"
     value="../images/images1.jpg" />
   </h:panelGrid>
   <p:commandButton value="Crop" action="#{profilePicture.crop}"
    update="localCroppedImage" />
  </h:form>
 </ui:define>
</ui:composition>